# Codes in book that comes with the game

Tags: super-mario-maker

The Super Mario Maker book (also available [on Nintendo's website](http://www.nintendo.co.jp/wiiu/amaj/booklet/SuperMarioMakerBooklet.pdf)) has a number of pictures in it with a key icon followed by a 4-digit number.

I assume these are used in-game somewhere... but what are these numbers used for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open the in-game manual, the Main Page of the manual has an icon with a key and four empty squares.

If you choose this icon and enter one of the video IDs, it will show a "hidden" video.